# Are Python 3 and sqlite3 enough for a socket login and how much do I expect to handle before it falls down?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sqlite, sockets

I have a `saved_auth` table within an `auth.db` sqlite3 database on the user's side (inside an `android.apk`) and a thread that runs `func_auth_socket()`.

Here is a part of the thread:

```py
def func_auth_socket():
    global auth_packet, auth_packet_answer, username, conto_auth_socket, decoded_auth_packet_answer, holdermsg
    while conto_auth_socket == False:
      try:
        auth_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        auth_socket.connect(('192.168.1.138', 3367))
        print('connected')
        print('after conn '+ auth_packet)
        while True:
            if auth_packet != '':
                print('sending auth packet: ' + auth_packet)    
                auth_socket.send(bytes(auth_packet, 'utf-8'))
                auth_packet_answer = auth_socket.recv(100)  
                decoded_auth_packet_answer = auth_packet_answer.decode("utf-8")
                print(decoded_auth_packet_answer)
                conto_auth_socket = True
                print(conto_auth_socket)
                auth_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                auth_socket.close()
                break

                if decoded_auth_packet_answer == 'match':
                    username = auth_packet.split('|')[0]
                    print('recieved username: ' + username )                                
                    auth_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                    auth_socket.close()

                elif decoded_auth_packet_answer == 'unmatch':
                    auth_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                    auth_socket.close()
                        
                else:
                    pass
      except:
        
        holdermsg = 'Initializing'
        time.sleep(0.5)
        holdermsg = 'Initializing  .'
        time.sleep(0.5)
        holdermsg = 'Initializing  ..'
        time.sleep(0.5)
        holdermsg = 'Intializing  ...'
```

and inside the gui loop (threading kivy mainapp) I have this with some update functions:

```py
def fun_socket_auth():
    global auth_response2, auth_response1




    socket_auth = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket_auth.bind(('192.168.1.138', 3416))
    socket_auth.listen(10)
    while True:
        linktoauth = sqlite3.connect('USERS.db')
        curs = linktoauth.cursor()

        clientsocket, address = socket_auth.accept()
        print(address[0])
        while True:

            auth_request = clientsocket.recv(100)
            string_auth = auth_request.decode("utf-8")
            user = string_auth.split('|')[0]
            print(string_auth)
            curs.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", (user,))
            select = curs.fetchone()

            if select == None:

                clientsocket.send(bytes('unmatch', "utf-8"))
                auth_request= ''
                string_auth = ''
                user = ''
                break       
            elif select[0]+'|'+ select[1] == user+'|'+ string_auth.split('|')[1]:
            #if auth_request.decode("utf-8") == 'user|password':  

                clientsocket.send(bytes('match', "utf-8"))
                auth_request = ''
                string_auth = ''
                user = ''
                break
            else:
                
                clientsocket.send(bytes('unmatch', "utf-8"))
                auth_request = ''
                string_auth = ''
                user = ''

                break


            #   pass    
fun_socket_auth()
```

This base model is working fine for a couple of virtual machines and I also can edit the server side to store every `clientsocket` in a list then answer to it, but the question is how do I know if I am overloaded with requests to what should I compare it? Is sqlite3 fast enough? Should I split the requests into two different servers, or different threads?.

Comment: Ignoring that your code can't work (calling fetchone multiple times for each check won't work like you expect), there isn't really an answer to "how much do I expect to handle before it falls down?"  That depends on how much work you're doing, the speed of the machine, and other factors.  Test it, profile the application, and if responses aren't fast enough, fix the parts taking the longest time to execute.

Comment: @AnonCoward thank you. A None type error got me to fix it (now edited). i always split the work to many socket threads with different ports, i dont know if adding a simple line from a module like sqlite3 will load the socket and create delays for the end users, though if i have a 100 bytes sent through each socketclient  and X number of users i know i ll consume 100*X bytes of my bandwidth if i am to respond to them all at the same time, but what about RAM, CPU... that's what bothers me really. and srry i m new to the stackoverflow community.